# How to match a pattern and replace another

Tags: bash, shell

I have a .pro file which contains a line "Max_length: 123". I need to take a usser input value, eg: 145, and reframe line like"Max_length: 145". How?

Comment: not clear, please put more information with sample Input_file and expected output too here.

Comment: I have to replace the numerical value in "Max_length: 123" with a user input value, inside a file. 123 is not hard-coded, it can vary.

Answer (score 1):

```
read var
awk -v var=$var '$0 ~ /Max_length:/ { print "Max_length:"var } $0 !~ /Max_length:/ { print $0 }' oldfile > newfile
mv newfile oldfile
```

Read in the input into variable var. Pass this to awk as a variable and in the case where the line in the file oldfile, pattern matches against "Max_length:" print the text along with the line. In all cases, just print the line. Redirect the output to a newfile and then rename the newfile oldfile.

Comment: I like the `read var`. ^

Comment: Here I need to grep for a line like "Max_length: 123", how to store it in a variable?

Comment: var=$(grep "Max_length: 123" filename)

Comment: I am not clear. In my file, there is a line Max_length:xxx(can vary). I need to replace it like Max_length:yyy, whre yyy is a user input value. issue is with xxx, which is a variable

Comment: This is what the solution does? xxx can be any value. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i tried..But not working..Is there any sed command which does the same?

Comment: You cannot pass dynamic values to sed unfortunately. I tested the scenario you have with my code and it worked fine. What is the output when you run with the command on your system. An extract of some of the data you have may also be beneficial.

Comment: It is coming with both values, if I am giving 123, o/p is like :Max-Length: 123 :133.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
Max_length: 123
Foo: 666
$ awk -v v=145 '$1=="Max_length:"{$2=v}1' file
Max_length: 145
Foo: 666
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v v=145 '     # using awk, set desired value to v
$1=="Max_length:"{   # if Max_... in the first field
    $2=v             # replace second with v
}1' file             # output
```

Comment: 123 is not a hardcoded value.

Comment: @Anony It's not hardcoded in my code, either: _if "Max_length:" in the first field ... replace second with v_ User inputs his desired value by setting `-v v=145`. If you want something more interactive, use @RamanSailopal's `read var` and `-v v=$var`.

Answer (score 0):

```
read val && sed -i -e s/"`grep Max_length: $file_name>`"/"Max_length: $val"/g file_name
```

Where *file_name* is the file path.

This script would change the **Max_length** from any value to the user provided input.

Comment: I tried like this and it worked!!... var=$(grep "Max-Length:" ABC.txt | cut -d ":" -f 2),wher I am getting the 123 ( or any value ) in var , sed "s/Max-Length: `echo $var`/Max-Rec-Length: `echo $size`/", where size is the new user input value..Thanku all for the help :)